# Complexity of algorithms of different programming paradigms

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, programming-languages, functional-programming, complexity-theory

I know that most programming languages are Turing complete, but I wonder whether a problem can be resolved with an algorithm of the same complexity with any programming language (and in particular with any programming paradigm).

To make my answer more explicit with an example: is there any problem which can be resolved with an imperative algorithm of complexity `x` (say `O(n)`), but cannot be resolved by a functional algorithm with the same complexity (or vice versa)?

**Edit:** *The algorithm itself can be different.* The question is about the complexity of solving the problem -- using any approach available in the language.

Comment: Ermmm, no, like your question is tagged, algorithms are language-agnostic.

Comment: @leppie: hum, well, I'm not so sure about it, that's why I'm asking... An imperative algorithm cannot usually be implemented with a purely functional language, for example.

Comment: @leppie I like to write code that runs in both Prolog and C. Makes for the most interesting puzzles.

Comment: @peoro This question is asking about just a matter of complexity to solving an problem and not to a the approach required for a *specific* algorithm choice then? E.g. can the algorithm be substituted to maintain the complexity? It seems like there would be a counter-example, if that is indeed the case.

Comment: @pst: yes, I'd like to know whether a given problem can be resolved with the same complexity in any language or not.

Comment: In complexity do you also include space complexity?

Comment: @Moron: I asked this question with time complexity in mind, but now that you make me think about it yes, I'm also interested in space complexit.

Comment: I tend to think that the complexity of an algorithm is a property of the implementation and not the language itself.  E.g., imagine a brainfuck implementation that makes certain optimizations so that when particular well-known loops are entered with the tape in "compatible" states, the universe is 'instantaneously' updated with the net result of the loop (say, an O(1) seek).  Then, users who need random access "simply" make sure to use the system in the prescribed way so that the optimizations will fire.

Comment: Who can vote to close this?  This is a very cool and interesting programming question...  I'll vote to re-open if needed.

Comment: Extending to what @mokus says, let's not consider extreme cases like Brainfuck, but just something more practical like Haskell. If Haskell cannot optimize tail recursion at compile time, an algorithm that runs `t` operations (say `t` clock cycles) would require O(t) memory (either in the writable memory or in the compiled code, but the latter needs to be loaded into memory by the OS anyway).

Comment: Speaking of that, it is not just the language runtime that defines the possible time complexities, but also the OS and the hardware. For example, if you are running code for a poorly designed hardware TEE, you might end up accumulating more and more to decrypt as your number of operations grows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, no, not all algorithms can be implemented with the same order of complexity in all languages.  This can be trivially proven, for instance, with a hypothetical language that disallows O(1) access to an array.  However, there aren't any algorithms (to my knowledge) that cannot be implemented with the optimal order of complexity in a functional language.  The complexity analysis of an algorithm's pseudocode makes certain assumptions about what operations are legal, and what operations are O(1).  If you break one of those assumptions, you can alter the complexity of the algorithm's implementation even though the language is Turing complete.  Turing-completeness makes no guarantees regarding the complexity of any operation.

Comment: It could be, though I'm not sure, that a PURE functional language may not be able to implement an algorithm where the big-O of space is x (not n), and the big-O of time is asymptotically less than log(x).

Comment: Most functional languages lack a data structure able to  represent an ordered collection (as for instance an array) allowing to change its contents with O(1) complexity. Best you can get is O(log N).

Comment: +1 to salva about pure-functional update.  To be fair, though, the actual performance of O(log N) "pure" datastructures can be comparable to O(1) destructive update, due to cache behavior and other considerations.

Answer (score 4):

An algorithm has a measured runtime such as O(n) like you said, implementations of an algorithm must adhere to that same runtime or they do not implement the algorithm. The language or implementation does not by definition change the algorithm and thus does not change the asymptotic runtime.

That said certain languages and technologies might make expressing the algorithm easier and offer constant speedups (or slowdowns) due to how the language gets compiled or executed.

Comment: So any problem can be resolved both in C and in brainfuck, or lisp, or prolog or C++ templates with algorithms of the same complexity?

Comment: Unless someone can produce a counter example I believe that is correct.

Comment: Should be correct. However, that shifts the question to "can all language implement all algorithms" (which is *not* the same as "can they all compute the same things", as there are often several algorithms for one problem) - I'm not quite sure what the answer is. Are the functional languages so pure they can't emulate state?

Comment: @Andrew: Counter example: I can find a given number in a sorted array of numbers in `log n` time in C, but not in brainfuck.

Comment: @sepp2k: using the same algo?

Comment: @Andrew: I'm saying you can't do it in brainfuck using any algo.

Comment: @sepp2k: are you sure about it? Of course if you _store_ your array on N consecutive cells you can't _jump_ to a random cell, but I think that maybe you could be able to store your array in a way that will allow random access somehow...

Comment: @peoro: Random access is Brainfuck is O(n) in the distance from the current cell.  The binary search algorithm cannot be implemented with log(n) time since it involves jumping over areas of memory that are proportional to n.

Comment: Agreed, Brainfuck as usually implemented is a very good example of a Turing-complete machine that can't do much of anything in any reasonable O(_) time.  It can't even load an arbitrary integer `n` into a cell in less than O(n) time.

Comment: @mokus No language (nor thinkable computer) can load an _arbitrary_  integer in less than O(n). What change from one to another are the multiplication constants.

Comment: @belisarius: I was simplifying rather than go into all that pedantry, but I stand by my point that a BF implementation will typically take an absolute minimum of n cycles to load the number n into a cell, for any arbitrary integer that the machine can represent. Sure, if cells are bounded, this amounts to O(1), but by finiteness of the state space of every "real" computer it could also be said that every algorithm executable on any particular real computer runs in O(1), but that's rather disingenious.  It is still the case that something we take for granted is spectacularly expensive in BF.

Comment: @belisarius:  Actually, I missed one more thing:  Most computers routinely _DO_ load arbitrary integers into O(log n) space.  Given that it is representable in that space, an arbitrary integer constant is in O(log n) time.  In BF, this is not possible without representing the integer across multiple cells, which is certainly what i'd be doing if trying to represent a large integer in BF.  Each cell then takes O(b) (b is base of representation) time to initialize, which is arguably O(1) since you can make b small.  So with a suitable representation BF can load a number in O(log n) too.

Comment: (continued) However, typical code (if any BF code could be called "typical" that is) still runs into the limitation I'm describing.  Imagine a BF machine with 64-bit signed integers backing the cells.  Assuming the machine can execute 1 billion `+` per second, it would still take about 292 years to initialize a cell to MAXINT.  Even for 32-bit integers it can take over 2 seconds at that rate to initialize a cell to an arbitrary (representable) integer, and that rate is pretty generous.  It assumes zero overhead for loops and such that are used to construct the number, which isn't realistic.

Comment: It is always possible for a brainfuck runtime to optimize standard operations like `[-]`. You know, in some more ancient designs of RAM, the RAM probe might take O(n) time to move from bit 0x0000 to 0x000f, and in that case it is not O(1) time anymore. Of course you can argue that it is not "random access" memory anymore, but no memory is truly random access anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a language can have different basilar operations that cost O(1), for example mathematical operations (+, -, *, /), or variable/array access (a[i]), function call and everything you can think.

If a language do not have one of this O(1) operations (as brain bending that do not have O(1) array access) it can not do everything C can do with same complexity, but if a language have more O(1) operations (for example a language with O(1) array search) it can do more than C.

I think that all "serious" language have the same basilar O(1) operations, so they can resolve problem with same complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I think your first paragraph is wrong. And I think your edit doesn't change that.

Assuming you are requiring that the observed behaviour of an implementation conforms to the time complexity of the algorithm, then...

When calculating the complexity of an algorithm assumptions are made about what operations are constant time. These assumptions are where you're going to find your clues.

Some of the more common assumptions are things like constant time array access, function calls, and arithmetic operations.

If you cannot provide those operations in a language in constant time you cannot reproduce the algorithm in a way that preserves the time complexity.

Reasonable languages can break those assumptions, and sometimes have to if they want to deal with, say, immutable data structures with shared state, concurrency, etc.

For example, Clojure uses trees to represent Vectors. This means that access is not constant time (I think it's log32 of the size of the array, but that's not constant even though it might as well be).

You can easily imagine a language having to do complicated stuff at runtime when calling a function. For example, deciding which one was meant.

Once upon a time floating point and multi-word integer multiplication and division were sadly not constant time (they were implemented in software). There was a period during which languages transitioned to using hardware when very reasonable language implementations behaved very differently.

I'm also pretty sure you can come up with algorithms that fare very poorly in the world of immutable data structures. I've seen some optimisation algorithms that would be horribly difficult, maybe impossible or effectively so, to implement while dealing immutability without breaking the time complexity.

For what it's worth, there are algorithms out there that assume set union and intersection are constant time... good luck implementing those algorithms in constant time. There are also algorithms that use an 'oracle' that can answer questions in constant time... good luck with those too.

Comment: Well, any algorithm that assumes real numbers is potential source of fun. Those algorithms assume constant time operations like division, and at the same time assume accuracy of the operation. For a classic, consider matrix inversion. There are degenerate cases on the order of 7x7 that introduce incredible error into the result if floating point numbers are used. If you use arbitrary precision arithmetic then those algorithms are not constant time anymore. If the implementation gives the wrong answer because of numeric representation it isn't a true implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) or the Turing machine itself, there is one fundamental operation, that takes O(n) time there, although in most other languages it can be done in O(1) – indexing an array.

I'm not completely sure about this, but I think you can't have true array in functional programming either (having O(1) “get element at position” *and* O(1) “set element at position”). Because of immutability, you can either have a structure that can change quickly, but accessing it takes time or you will have to copy large parts of the structure on every change to get fast access. But I guess you could cheat around that using monads.

Comment: You can cheat using any sort of analysis that detects when an array is used in such a way that, once updated, the old version is never touched again.  You can't detect all instances of that usage pattern, but if there are at least _some_ cases where you can recognize it, then you can have the compiler generate code that does O(1) in-place mutation in those cases.  Monads are a popular trick for this because it's fairly easy to invent a monad that makes it very, very clear that such a pattern holds (by hiding the 'real' array from the user so that they can't possibly misuse it).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at things like functional versus imperative, I doubt you'll find any real differences.

Looking at individual languages and implementations is a different story though. Ignoring, for the moment, the examples from Brainfuck and such, there are still some pretty decent examples to find.

I still remember one example from many years ago, writing APL (on a mainframe). The task was to find (and eliminate) duplicates in a sorted array of numbers. At the time, most of the programming I'd done was in Fortran, with a few bits and pieces in Pascal (still the latest and greatest thing at the time) or BASIC. I did what seemed obvious: wrote a loop that stepped through the array, comparing `array[i]` to `array[i+1]`, and keeping track of a couple of indexes, copying each unique element back the appropriate number of places, depending on how many elements had already been eliminated.

While this would have worked quite well in the languages to which I was accustomed, it was barely short of a disaster in APL. The solution that worked a lot better was based more on what was easy in APL than computational complexity. Specifically, what you did was compare the first element of the array with the first element of the array after it had been "rotated" by one element. Then, you either kept the array as it was, or eliminated the last element. Repeat that until you'd gone through the whole array (as I recall, detected when the first element was smaller than the first element in the rotated array).

The difference was fairly simple: like most APL implementations (at least at the time), this one was a pure interpreter. A single operation (even one that was pretty complex) was generally pretty fast, but interpreting the input file took quite a bit of time. The improved version was much shorter and faster to interpret (e.g., APL provides the "rotate the array" thing as a single, primitive operation so that was only a character or two to interpret instead of a loop).